# vibration api for xbox 360 controller

Tags: javascript, xbox360, vibration

Is there any way to get the Vibration API to work with the xbox 360 controller? Or any other way to get it to rumble with javascript? It is for a firefox extension written in javascript and the Gamepad API works flawless, but I really need to make the controller vibrate.

I have tried it on different "check if your device is supported by the Vibration API"-tests without any result. Thank you in before hand!

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite old, but anyway:

– As of the end of 2017, there is no native / Web-API way to make a controller "rumble" via javascript. The Gamepad API does not provide a rumble feature yet.

**Possible solution (Workaround):**

You can use NodeJS whether you are using electron / NWjs as a wrapper or just on your website. There is a node Module for Xbox in nodeJS, which also can activate the rumble motor of the controllers: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xbox-controller

**Issues**

Since this is nodeJS, the implementation depends on your use-case. For those who use **Electron**: beware, there are several issues due to node-version conflicts with dependencies of this module.

*Hope that helps anyone who still stumbles upon this.*

Answer (score 1):

Update 2023:

I found this [resource](https://www.voorhoede.nl/en/blog/navigating-the-web-with-a-gamepad/#-adding-feedback-with-vibrations):

It seems that there's a functionality for talking to rumble:

```
gamepad.vibrationActuator.playEffect('dual-rumble', {
  startDelay: 0, // Add a delay in milliseconds
  duration: 1000, // Total duration in milliseconds
  weakMagnitude: 0.5, // intensity (0-1) of the small ERM 
  strongMagnitude: 1 // intesity (0-1) of the bigger ERM
});
```

I haven't tested it yet, but a quick "can I use...?" search revealed support in fairly new browsers (except Firefox; maybe serve a warning popup?):

https://caniuse.com/?search=vibrationActuator